# Multidimensional array column sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

assume i create this code to generate the idv-th random number. But i have a difficulty in sorting the array depends on the last column.

let say the individual size is [idv, width] = [8,6]
and i want to sort all the row with column 6th... and i want to take the 4 top list in the array after it sorted. How can i implement this case to the code??

```
public static void population(double[,] individual, int width, int idv, Random rnd)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < idv; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("individual {0} :\t", i+1);
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                individual[i, j] = Math.Round(rnd.NextDouble() * 10, 2);
                Console.Write("{0} ", individual[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: I suggest using *jagged arrays* `double[][] individual` instead of 2d ones.

Comment: as `Dmitry` wrote. multidimensional arrays are an half-baked/incomplete "subsystem".

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you using *jagged arrays* `double[][]` instead of *2d* ones `double[,]`. Jagged array is just an *array of array* which you can easily sort, filter, etc. usually with a help of *Linq*:

```
  double[][] individual = new double[][] {
    new double[] {81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86},
    new double[] {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16},
    new double[] {41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46},
    new double[] {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36},
    new double[] {51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56},
    new double[] {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26},
    new double[] {61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66},
    new double[] {71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76},
  };

  double[][] fragment = individual
    .OrderBy(line => line[line.GetUpperBound(0)]) // by last column
    .Take(4) 
    .ToArray();
```

One more Linq to test the results:

```
  String test = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, fragment
    .Select(line => String.Join("\t", line)));

  Console.Write(test);
```

The result is

```
11  12  13  14  15  16
21  22  23  24  25  26
31  32  33  34  35  36
41  42  43  44  45  46
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use multidimensional arrays, there's no easy way to work with them using LINQ, you'll need to rely on good old `for`.

```
static void Main ()
{
    // Input array
    double[,] u = {
        { 1, 9, 3 },
        { 0, 3, 4 },
        { 3, 4, 5 },
        { 3, 6, 8 },
        { 3, 5, 7 },
    };

    // Get dimension sizes, specify column to order by
    int count = u.GetLength(0), length = u.GetLength(1), orderBy = 2;
    // Result array
    double[,] v = new double[count, length];
    // Construct a list of indices to sort by
    var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, count).OrderBy(i => u[i, orderBy]).ToList();
    // Copy values from input to output array, based on these indices
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            v[i, j] = u[indices[i], j];

    PrintArray(u);
    Console.WriteLine();
    PrintArray(v);
}

static void PrintArray (double[,] a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
            Console.Write(a[i, j]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

If you need only top 4 rows, you can add `Take(4)` before `ToList()` call and adjust result array creation and copying of values into it appropriately.

Multidimenional arrays are more efficient and use less memory, so if your arrays are big enough or you need to work with them faster, you may need to write a little more code and use multidimenional arrays instead of jagged arrays which are easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

For rectangular array `[,]` you can copy the desired column in a single-dimensional array together with indices, sort it, and then get rows with first 4 indices.

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, double>> GetColumn(int columnIndex, double[,] a)
{
    for (int i = a.GetLowerBound(0); i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        yield return Tuple.Create(i, a[i, columnIndex]);
}

double [,] data = ...;
var column = GetColumn(4, data);
var top4Indices = column.OrderBy(v => v.Second)
                        .Take(4)
                        .Select(v => v.First);

foreach (int i in top4Indices)
    for (int j = data.GetLowerBound(1); j <= data.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        data[i, j]...
```